# Why vacuum permittivity ($\epsilon_0$) isn't infinite?

Tags: electrostatics

Hellow, one can understand the word "permit" as to allow or admit. So the electrostatic allowance would be zero then for a conductor, and infinite for a vacuum where a field is free.

That confused me more where there exists a similar but inverse question "Why isn't vacuum permittivity zero?"

Point me out the error. You can even add a concise comment and delete that question if its to trivial but i dont understan it.

Comment: If the name of the constant were different, would you have the same question?  Are you confused about the name "permittivity," or are you confused about the existence of the constant $\epsilon_0$ in expressions like $F = kqQ/4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2$?

Comment: Interpreting physics through English language word usage and evolution seems inadvisable.

Comment: @J.Murray i'm not confused about a constant that refers to an experimental fact. The theory behind that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @J.Murray that formula is completely fine to me but then in the space force would be =zero.

Comment: @konto It is not even experimental facts or the theory behind... but the choice of the SI system of units. E.g., in cgs vacuum permittivity is $1$.

Comment: @RogerVadim how would you select units to get to the infinity?

Comment: It is not infinity - it is simply not there... but the SI system fixed the units of electric and magnetic fields in such a way that one needs an additional constant to get the correct results. Just compare the [Maxwell equations in the two systems of units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Formulation_in_SI_units_convention)

Comment: @RogerVadim but how something can be more permittive that the vacum?

Comment: @konto also you need to learn about the difference between an absolute and relative permittivity.

Comment: Related, and might answer the question:  [Why is Permittivity of free space or vacuum not Zero 0?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/361125/why-is-permittivity-of-free-space-or-vacuum-not-zero-0?rq=1)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert ok, so thank you from the answer you provided it seems that a correct term would be "electrostatic conductance"? for me it would not cause the confusion.

Comment: @konto there are materials for which epsilon goes below one, and for metals, epsilon is negative!